# Prove that every $ A \in M_n\left ( \mathbb{C} \right )$ is similar to a matrix with at most one non-zero element in the first column

Tags: linear-algebra

I need that prove that every $ A \in M_n\left ( \mathbb{C} \right )$ is similar to a matrix $B$ where $B$'s first column is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\0\\\vdots\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

where $M_n\left ( \mathbb{C} \right ) $ is the set of all square matrices above $\mathbb{C}$.

I haven't been able to make much progress with this question - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every complex matrix is triangularizable, because its characteristic polynomial factorises completely into linear factors. Hence A is similar to an upper-triangular matrix. The first column of such a matrix has the desired form.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a complex $n\times n$ matrix, then it has an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Hence we can choose a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ for $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $v_1$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and the matrix of $A$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ will have the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is similar to its Jordan normal form $J$ which has the desired form.